# In SSRS how do I create a parameter for time only?

Tags: sql-server, time, reporting-services, parameters

I have an appointments report and want to have separate parameter for the date and time.  I can create a date parameter, but I don't see an option for time only.  Is it possible to create a time parameter only parameter?